# Find all primes of the form

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all primes of the form $3\cdot2^{2^t-1}+1$.

For $t=1$ it works.And I was thinking that it should have some logic because the other numbers go really large and is meaningless to take them one by one.

Comment: Looking at the first values: Try to prove that for $t>1$ you have $3\cdot2^{2^t-1}+1\equiv 0 \pmod 5$

Comment: @Gammatester, why don't you write up some hints in an answer? I was preparing to do it myself, but you got there first. Will +1 your answer, of course.

Answer (score 3):

For $t>1$, the expression can never be prime.

Modulo 5 we get

$3 \cdot 2^{2^t - 1} + 1 \equiv (-2) \cdot 2^{2^t - 1} + 1 \mod 5$

$\equiv - 2^{2^t} + 1 \mod 5$

Since $t>1$, write $2^t = 4\cdot 2^{t-2}$. So $2^{2^t} = (2^4)^{2^{t-2}}$ and

$- 2^{2^t} + 1 \equiv -(2^4)^{2^{t-2}} + 1 \mod 5$

$\equiv -(1^{2^{t-2}}) + 1 \equiv 0 \mod 5$

Since the expression is obviously greater than 5, it follows that it is never prime.